# Where can I find FOIA requests to NASA and their subsequent replies?

Tags: nasa, foia

NASA official page compiles Freedom of Information Act (FOIA) information requests here.

https://www.nasa.gov/FOIA/elibrary

Above page lists few xlsx files for past few years but links given for individual FOIA information requests appear to not work. For example

For tracking number **19-HQ-F-00003** this is the broken link.

https://foia.nasa.gov/FOIAXpress/Reports/RequestDetail/RequestDetailReport.aspx?RequestID=10575&fromExport=Y

For tracking number **19-JPL-F-00005** this is the broken link.

https://foia.nasa.gov/FOIAXpress/Reports/RequestDetail/RequestDetailReport.aspx?RequestID=10579&&fromExport=Y

Are there any alternate webpages to refer to for FOIA replies by NASA?

Comment: You can find individual center (JSC, KSC, etc) FOIA pages here. https://www.nasa.gov/centers/johnson/news/foia.html

I haven't checked them all, but mostly they just seem to post the documents that were asked for, without much rationale. So not too helpful.